# Making sure loop continues to make API calls even if one failed

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, raspberry-pi

If I request data from an API using a raspberry pi in a while/for loop in python and append data to csv and one iteration fails due to something like faulty wifi connection that comes and goes, what is a foolproof method of having an indication that an error occurred and have it keep trying again either immediately or after some rest period?

Answer (score 2):

Use `try/except` to catch the exception, e.g.:

```py
while True:
  try:
    my_function_that_sometimes_fails()
  except Exception e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess [retry](https://pypi.org/project/retry/) package (and decorator) will suit your needs. You can specify what kind of exception it should catch and how many times it should retry before stopping completely. You can also specify the amount of time between each try.